# WP loop filtering with ACF values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How to filter by ACF fields in WP loop?

```
    <?php
    $company = the_field('company');
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
              'post_type' => 'jobs',
              'posts_per_page' => '100',
              'meta_key' => 'company',  
              'meta_value' =>  the_field('company')

              )
              );
              ?>

            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'components/loop' );?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

If the meta_value is a string it works. Wondering how to make this work dynamically.

Comment: 'meta_value' =>  get_field('company')

Comment: Is my suggested answer works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead of `the_field`. You can print custom-filed values with the `get_field` function.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'jobs',
        'posts_per_page' => '100',
        'meta_key'       => 'company',
        'meta_value'     => get_field('company'),

    )
);
?>
    <?php while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();?>
        <?php get_template_part('components/loop');?>
    <?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();?>
```